# UGC in Dynamic Component Presentations?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery, ugc

I am having a problem using the UGC framework in conjunction with dynamic component presentations.

When I publish a CP as 'embedded on page', my UGC tags are converted from  to  nicely and I am able to leave ratings etc. However, if I create a dynamic version of the same CT/CP, what gets deployed to the Broker, is the same component presentation, with the  stripped out.

Is there a limitation here that I am not aware of, or maybe some missing configuration?

Any thoughts would be very welcome.

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you doubt whether your configuration is correct, it helps if you share the **section that you doubt**. Also be aware that Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions, things that have a clear answer. The format of the site is not ideally suited for trouble shooting, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Please note also that if it's about the configuration of your system, there are also tridion-related questions over on Server Fault. In particular, this one http://serverfault.com/questions/401626/tridion-content-delivery-tcdl-not-rendered-in-rel-dcp is relevant. So far, it's unanswered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you will need to check the output format of your Dynamic CT - Make sure it is set to the same as your target (REL, ASP.NET, JSP etc), and not set to None or HTML

Comment: Chris, as you suspected, my Dynamic CT had the Output format set as HTML. Changing it to ASCX WebControl as per the documentation did the trick. I guess I have never changed that setting before! Thanks for the advice, Daniel

Comment: Glad it helped - As this solved your problem, please consider voting for and accepting this answer to help others with the same question

Comment: I am now experimenting between ASCX and REL formats.  I wanted all the dynamic content in the Broker DB, and ASCX requires the component presentations to be published to the file system.    Based on other posts/documentation I understood that setting the output format as REL, with my target being .NET, the ComponentPresentationAssembler would resolve the tcdl tags into ugc tags, however they are still being rendered as tcdl in the final output.  Hopefully someone out there has had success with UGC and dynamic component presentations!

Comment: To ensure my setup is correct, I also added a dynamic link to the dynamic component presentations. These work as expected. Therefore my assertion is that when the ugc tag bundle was added in the latest release, the handling of those tags in ComponentPresentationAssembler was not added!

Comment: Hi Daniel, it would help if you could accept this question, and post a new one. The discussion of output formats is really a different subject,and will have a lot of sub-questions and answers which will confuse answers to this one. Perhaps consider a question called "How do I make UGC DCPs work with REL?" and outline the code you see published to the DB, and what you are seeing in the output response when you visit the final page.